# Rails: How to create an url shortener?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure if `url shortener` is the right name for it, because most of the search results point toward things like `bit.ly`.

So, here is what I want:
Given url strings like:

```
http://avc.com
http://firstround.com/review/feed/
http://svpg.com/articles/
http://www.medium.com/ 
http://www.paulgraham.com/
```

Turn it into

```
avc.com
firstround.com
svpg.com
medium.com
paulgraham.com
```

No subdomain, no subdirectory, no `/`.

I can do something like `url.split('://')[1].split('/')[0]`, but cannot get rid of the `www`, and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [URI module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) and then use a regexp to parse out the first www. Like

```
def host(url)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    uri.host.sub(/^www./, '')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [URI](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri) class.

```
% irb
> require 'uri'
 => true 
> u = URI('http://firstround.com/review/feed/')
 => #<URI::HTTP http://firstround.com/review/feed/> 
> u.host
 => "firstround.com"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not deal with the prefix `www`, Valdim's answer is better.